# TranslateZ() does not being rendered without Preserve-3d

Tags: html, css, transform

According to this http://jsfiddle.net/4ESUW/3/ example, I am trying to adjust Z axis position by `translateZ()` but It behaves so strange.

I donot want to use `preserve-3d` because it affects to div position, which I need for making further interaction.

Anybody has ideas or clues how to make use of `translateZ()` without `preserve-3d`

I am running this example on Chrome version 19.0.1084.56. Unfortunately, it seems not work on Firefox as well.

Comment: What is meant by "behaves so strange"? Do you refer to the fact that the mouse behaviour is not registered on the visual representation of the Element but on the former position it had (without perserve-3d)?

Comment: fix for the events in http://jsfiddle.net/6hJhv/9/ (using a nested element)

Comment: it works well in jsfiddle. However, when I applied to my site, it still has bug. We can see together when you come to the office. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you contradict yourself in your statement: You want to use a translation but don't want to affect the position of the div???

Despite this, it can't work without `preserve-3d`, because the Definition of the `transform-style` property is whether the child-elements exist in their own 3d-space (`preserve-3d`) or are flattened and are restricted to the plane of the parent-element (`transform-style:flat`) which is the default (non inheritable) value.

So if you want to use any transformations involving the z-axis (e.g. translateZ and rotateX/Y), you always have to set `transform-style:preserve-3d`. Otherwise they are bound to the z-plane of their parent element.

For more info, have a look at the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform-style).

Comment: thanks for replying, Without `preserve-3d`, I tried setting `perspective()` to the child and it seems to take an effect.

Comment: perspective acts differently by defining the Difference of the user to the z-plane. If you define it explicitely on an element, you declare a new stacking index for that element. You may want to read this [very nice intro](http://24ways.org/2010/intro-to-css-3d-transforms/) about css transform to get further info.